# In Entity Framework, can a complex type have a property of a complex type?

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework, can a complex type have a property of a complex type?

If `Employee` is the complex type, can it have a property `Supervisor` of type `Employee`? It forms a cycle basically. I would like to know whether this is valid or not according to Entity Framework.

Also is it a valid according to OData specification?

Please add your comments/views. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean 'property' instead of 'attribute'?

Comment: Yes Amy, I meant property. I was talking in a java context.